# Highcharts areaspline, charts crosshair

Tags: charts, highcharts, stacked-area-chart, react-highcharts

Hi all i have this chart 
http://i.prntscr.com/U1ho1cqRTVq-ifoMquWKAw.png
and i need  to get in result
http://i.prntscr.com/Lj_PqmNWSxiIBJmK3tS44Q.png

I think solution of this task in crosshair< but i start use highcharts one week ago. Can u help me or give some links that help solve problem. 
Because i refactored a lots of code all day and had not find solution of task.

My settings

```
chart: {
    type: 'areaspline',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    height: '500px',
    spacingRight: -1,
    spacingLeft: -1
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
subtitle: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    x: {
        min: 0,
        max: 0
    },
    allowDecimalse: false,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: '#393546',
    labels: {
        y: -20,
    },
    tickWidth: 0,
    lineColor: "#fff",
    zIndex: 0,
     **crosshair:** {
        color: 'rgba(73,168,222,0.5)',
        zIndex: 0
    }
},
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    visible: false,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},

plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    fillColor: '#fff',
                    lineColor: '#2196f3',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    radius: 7,
                    enabled: true,
                }
            },
        },
    }
},
series: [
    {
        data: [
        ],
        name: 'V/IRTUS',
        showInLegend: false,
        color: '#2196f3',
    }
],
credits: {
    enabled: false
}
```

};

data [] i get from api and categories too and min max  option

Comment: I do not think it can be achieved with a crosshair. You need to split the areaspline series into shapes for which the gradient should be applied - the paths need to be calculated based on series points or you can try to use zones. When you apply zones, shapes and clips will be created and you can use their coordinates to render the paths and apply the gradient. POC here http://jsfiddle.net/smsb8dx8/

Comment: thx i i finish this task)